# Codeigniter Model function get data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using the below function to get data from a mysql db

The code wrap from my mododel.php is:

```
 function get_all_devices($user_id = NULL) {
    if ($user_id) {
        $sql = "
            SELECT *
            FROM {$this->_db}
            WHERE user_id = " . $this->db->escape($user_id) . "

        ";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($query->num_rows()) {
            return $query->row_array();
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

The DB structure cols : `id, user_id, device, value`

But its extracting only the last record.
How can i get all the records in a array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `result_array()` instead of `row_array()`

```
function get_all_devices($user_id = NULL) {
    if ($user_id) {
        $sql = "
            SELECT *
            FROM {$this->_db}
            WHERE user_id = " . $this->db->escape($user_id) . "

        ";

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

it will return all records. `row_array()` return only one record

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll refactor the code and modify where needed:

```
function get_all_devices($user_id = NULL) {
        if ($user_id) {
            $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);// you don't have to escape `$user_id` value, since `$this->db->where()` escapes it implicitly. 
            $query = $this->db->get($this->_db); //executes `select *` on table `$this->_db`, and returns.     
            //if you want to get only specific columns, use $this->db->select('col1, col2'), otherwise you don't need to specify it, since it implicitly selects everything.     
            if ($query->num_rows()) {
                return $query->result_array();//use result_array() to retrieve the whole result instead of row_array() which retrieves only one row;
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```